# How to make the react native horizontal list always appears when the user scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React native question: I want to know how to implement the horizontal list ("Menu", "Info", "Reviews") like the video

I tried to use Translate y but it's not working properly, anyone can help me? [Attached video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10YRkfkASiSja18e4s7VhPFbR3RDhGxxD/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: First, try to reproduce what you want, and after show your code.

Comment: I want the horizontal list which contains the menu, info, photos, and reviews underneath the header when the user scroll as you can see in the video attached